# grep with piped date in Linux

Tags: linux, grep, command

I wanted to filter my date command in Linux by not having the Days printed out. So I tried to do something like this in the Linux terminal (for example):

```
date | grep -v 'Tuesday'
```

But, it didn't work . It prints nothing. Is this normal or did I make a mistake or something?

Comment: What does date (without grep) print?

Answer (score 3):

Date can print in almost any format you want.  To print the date and time without the day of the week:

```
$ date '+%D %r'
05/17/17 02:09:22 PM
```

`+%D %r` describes the format.  There are many possible formats.  See `man date` for details.

#### The pipeline command

```
date | grep -v 'Tuesday'
```

This does not remove the days.  It removes any line that contains the string `Tuesday`.  Examples:

```
$ date
Wed May 17 14:14:12 PDT 2017
$ date | grep -v 'Wed'
$ date | grep -v 'Thu'
Wed May 17 14:14:20 PDT 2017
```

Comment: Thanks! I learnt something new today...i thought that grep -v removes the string specified